# How to know the 3D coordinate position of mouse click in a-frame scene

Tags: three.js, aframe

I am not able to solve this. I looked other related three.js solutions at stack overflow but still not achieving the result. With the code below the 3D object appears some diagonal distant away from the mouse cursor when in mousedown click.

```
this.mouse = new THREE.Vector2();
this.scene = this.el.sceneEl;
this.camera = this.scene.camera;
this.obj = this.el.object3D;

this.scene.addEventListener('mousedown', e => {
    let rc = new THREE.Raycaster();
    rc.setFromCamera(this.mouse, this.camera);
    let dist = this.obj.position.distanceTo(this.camera.position);
    let point = rc.ray.direction.multiplyScalar(dist);
    document.querySelector('#red').setAttribute('position',point.x+'         
    '+point.y+' '+ point.z); //red is a 3D box
}
```

Is there any ready component for this?

Comment: Where do you set coordinates of `this.mouse`? And why not to use `let point = rc.ray.at(dist);` instead of `let point = rc.ray.direction.multiplyScalar(dist)`?

Comment: There are several examples on threejs.org, please, check them out : https://threejs.org/examples/?q=raycast

Comment: @prisoner849 using `let point = rc.ray.at(dist);` worked thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using

```
let point = rc.ray.at(dist);
```

instead of

```
let point = rc.ray.direction.multiplyScalar(dist);
```

worked